# Where can I Buy Kaima or Jeerakasala Rice?

Tags: rice, shopping, indian-cuisine

I'm trying to prepare an Indian Biriyani dish, and it calls for Kaima rice, also known as Jeerakasala. I understand that there are alternatives, like Basmati, but I really would love to try this particular variety. Where do you think I could purchase some (I live in the US, in  NC, ordering online would be great)?

If nothing else, could you suggest a rice that is extremely similar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you located? I haven't seen Kaima rice, but in my city (Houston, TX) there are several excellent ethnic food stores that would either carry it or find it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Kali Jeera rice available in most Patel stores or big indian stores. We were also looking for this and avoiding Kali Jeera thinking it is some black rice whereas it is not. This is rice used in Nor Malabar chicken biriyanis.

And no need to mention that ghee rice or biriyani prepared with Kali Jeera rice tastes way better than normal Basmati rice.

Answer (score 1):

Just search for the substitutes (they all taste more or less same)
Kaima(south india)
jeerakasala(south india)
ambhemohar(maharashtra)
Kalijira(bangladesh)
chinigura (bangladesh)